# JavaScript dialog delete error in Laravel 9

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-9

I want to create a confirmation dialog in JavaScript before deleting an item.

My JavaScript code

```
function confirmerSuppression() {
        var confirmation = confirm("Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cet élément ?");

        if (confirmation) {
            window.location.href = '/tiers.destroy/' + id; // 
        } else {
            alert("Suppression annulée !");
        }
    }
```

Code for my delete button

```
<form action="{{route('tiers.destroy', $tiers->id)}}" method="POST">
@csrf  
<button onclick="confirmerSuppression()" class="btn btn-danger w-100 type="submit">DELETE</button>                                 
</form>
```

My route:

```
Route::post('/tiers/details/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\tiersController::class, 'destroy'])->name('tiers.destroy');
```

My controller :

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        Tier::where("id","=",$id)->delete();
        return redirect()->route('prospects.liste')->with("success","Tier supprimée avec succès.");
    }
```

**When I click on the DELETE button the dialog appears and when I click on Cancel it deletes the element the same when I click on Yes.**

Anyone have an idea please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your code with this

```js
function confirmerSuppression(id) {
    var confirmation = confirm("Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cet élément ?");

    if (confirmation) {
        window.location.href = '/tiers.destroy/' + id;
    } else {
        alert("Suppression annulée !");
        return false; // Add this line to prevent form submission
    }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return confirmerSuppression({{ $row->id }})"  action="{{route('tiers.destroy', $row->id)}}" method="POST">
                                                    @csrf
                                                    <button class="btn btn-danger w-100" type="submit">Submit</button>
                                                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue might be related to how you're constructing the URL for deletion in your JavaScript code. The `id` variable is not defined within the `confirmerSuppression` function.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
function confirmerSuppression(id) {
    var confirmation = confirm("Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cet élément ?");

    if (confirmation) {
        window.location.href = '/tiers/details/' + id + '/destroy';
    } else {
        alert("Suppression annulée !");
    }
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
<form action="{{ route('tiers.destroy', $tiers->id) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf  
    <button type="button" onclick="confirmerSuppression({{ $tiers->id }})" class="btn btn-danger w-100">DELETE</button>                                 
</form>
```

Make sure to pass the `id` from your PHP code to the JavaScript function. Additionally, I adjusted the `button` type to "button" to prevent the form from being submitted before the confirmation.

Also, make sure your route definition in the routes file is using the correct URL structure:

```
Route::post('/tiers/details/{id}/destroy', [App\Http\Controllers\tiersController::class, 'destroy'])->name('tiers.destroy');
```

Now, the `id` should be properly passed to the `confirmerSuppression` function, and the URL should be constructed correctly for deletion.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/10871073